# Как сортировать список строк как числа?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Есть список студентов и их средний балл, каждого студента. Нужно отсортировать список по среднему баллу, но, когда я сортирую числа - string, и получается, что 100 меньше, чем 20 и т. д.

```py
file = open('Group1.csv','r')

next(file)

csv1=csv.reader(file,delimiter=',')

sort = sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(1))

for line in sort:
    print(line)
```

вот данные файла:

```
name,mark
Igor,74
Anton,75
Victor,66
A,100
```

Как сделать так, чтобы оно правильно сортировало и рядом с оценкой выводило и имя?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Это классическая библиотека для работы с данными, особенно с таблицами.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Group1.csv', sep=',')
df = df.sort__values('mark')

df.head()
```

Установка pandas очень проста:

```
pip install pandas
```

После этого Вы сможете выполнить тот код, который я привёл. Плюсы pandas в том, что он умеет работать с большим количеством данных. Например, если в столбце есть числа и только они, pandas сразу преобразует их числам. Если же есть пропущенные значения или строки, тогда pandas преобразует их к самому широкому типу. Например, к строкам.

Comment: Спасибо,очень полезно

Comment: @МаксимПронь если было полезно, вы можете проголосовать за мой ответ (=

Answer (score 0):

Конвертировать строку в число с помощью функции `int`:

```
key=int(operator.itemgetter(1))
```